# What are all the colors for os.system("color ??")

Tags: python, windows, terminal, os.system, ansi-escape

I know a couple...

- `0` is black
- `f` is white
- `a` is green

example..

```
    os.system("colora 0a")
```

I was wondering what other ones there were? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Color attributes are specified by TWO hex digits -- the first corresponds to the background; the second the foreground. Each digit can be any of the following values:

```
0 = Black       8 = Gray
1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
2 = Green       A = Light Green
3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
4 = Red         C = Light Red
5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
7 = White       F = Bright White
```

Source: http://dosprompt.info/commands/color.asp

Answer (score 0):

Actually 0 - 9 is text color, and A - F is background color of the console itself. At least on windows.

```
0 = Black       8 = Gray
1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
2 = Green       A = Light Green
3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
4 = Red         C = Light Red
5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
7 = White       F = Bright White
```